# NestJS app using SQLite errors over transactions on boot. How to appropriately set up a DB for many modules?

Tags: typescript, sqlite, nestjs, typeorm

I'm developing a small application, created a very small module, there were no major problems, created a more complicated one, still no problems.

Then I noticed that I had everything of the DB and entities in the AppModules, I decided to change that and spread the `forFeature` method among the other modules, so they called only what was necessary.

When I went to the third module, since I had made some large difference in the DB, I decided to just delete the sqlite file I had been using, and let it create everything again from scratch, however, I started getting errors over transactions straight from boot when running it.

I wondered if there could be some error in the entities, but they working until just before I made the large modifications and deleted the DB, and there were no errors that I could find.

So I tried using the cli command to sync, and it worked, migrations also worked. So I decided to delete the DB again to investigate.

After finding out about the logging option on the datasource, I found out that, whenever it boots, since the DB has to be synced from scratch, it was running everything 3 times simultaneously.

I'm guessing this is something other DBs would have little problem with, but with SQLite, there is. I was also wondering if my configuration could be wrong, or could be improved.

config/datasource.ts

```js
export const dataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: 'sqlite',
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  entities: [PlatformsEntity, GamesEntity, FilesEntity, PagesEntity],
  migrations: [__dirname + '/../migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: true,
  logging: true,
  migrationsRun: true,
};

// Necessary for TypeORM CLI/migrations and database.providers
const dataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);

export default dataSource;
```

I added the `migrationsRun` later after researching, so the error remains even if I disable it.

config/database.providers.ts

```js
import dataSource from './datasource';

export const databaseProvider = {
  provide: 'DATA_SOURCE',
  useFactory: async () => {
    return dataSource.initialize();
  },
};
```

This `DATA_SOURCE` is what I found as a way to inject it into services so I could use the same connection in all.

config/database.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule, TypeOrmModule.forRoot(dataSourceOptions)],
  providers: [databaseProvider],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule, databaseProvider],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

This Module was created later as I tried to find a way to centralize the connection outside of AppModule, trying to find a way to minimize the damage of the repetitions.

app.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    DatabaseModule,
    GameModule,
    PlatformModule,
    PageModule,
    // TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
    //   GamesEntity,
    //   PagesEntity,
    //   PlatformsEntity,
    //   FilesEntity,
    // ]),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: GenericExceptionFilter,
    },
    databaseProvider,
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

At first I had a `forRoot` in AppModule, but changed later as I considered moving the DB to the databaseModule

modules/game.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      GamesEntity,
      PagesEntity,
      FilesEntity,
      PlatformsEntity,
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [GameController],
  providers: [GameService, FileService, MinioService, databaseProvider],
  exports: [GameService, FileService],
})
export class GameModule {}
```

modules/platform.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [DatabaseModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([PlatformsEntity])],
  controllers: [PlatformController],
  providers: [PlatformService],
})
export class PlatformModule {}
```

modules/page.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([PagesEntity, FilesEntity]),
  ],
  controllers: [PageController],
  providers: [
    PageService,
    FileService,
    MinioService,
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: GenericExceptionFilter,
    },
    databaseProvider,
  ],
  exports: [PageService, FileService],
})
export class PageModule {}
```

A reminder, the problem happens on boot, meaning that I'm unable to run anything so long as the DB is not properly loaded.

From what I understood, I should use `forRoot` on TypeOrmModule only one time, to prepare the DB, and the `forFeature`, I'm guessing, are to prepare the appropriate entities of the DB towards the submodules. *(I could have understood it wrong, so I appreciate corrections)*

One behavior I noticed is that when I removed the `forFeature` from the imports, the number of calls in the DB decreased, however, my services broke because the injected dependencies didn't work anymore.

So after all this I'm guessing:

1. This could be a bug exclusive to SQLite that went unnoticed because of this limitation
2. This could be a problem in my code as I'm no specialist in NestJS and am using this project to experiment more with it.
3. The database and entities should always be centralized and what I thought was the best is actually bad.

I can't do much about 1, so I decided to ask about 2 and 3 with people who know more, and of course, check if there is a solution or a proper way of doing things.

Thank you very much for any help.